# Cannot access a LoadBalancer service at Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-service, amazon-ecr

I managed to deploy a python app at the kubernetes cluster . The python app image is deployed at AWS ECR (Elastic Container Registry). 

My deployment is:

> (**NAME**)charting-rest-server   
> (**READY**)1/1     
> (**UP-TO-DATE**)1           
>  (**AVAILABLE**)1           
> (**AGE**)33m  
>  (**CONTAINERS**)charting-rest-server  
>  (**IMAGES**) *****.dkr.ecr.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/charting-rest-server:latest 
>  (**SELECTOR**)app=charting-rest-server

And my service is:

> (**NAME**)charting-rest-server-service   
> (**TYPE**)LoadBalancer 
>   (**CLUSTER-IP**)10.100.4.207     
> (**EXTERNAL-IP**)*******.eu-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com   
> (**PORT(s)**)8765:32735/TCP               
>    (**AGE**)124m 
>   (**SELECTOR**)app=charting-rest-server

According to this [AWS guide](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/eks-kubernetes-services-cluster/) , when I do `curl *****.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com:80` I should be able to externally access the Load Balancer , who is going to route me to my pod's ip. 

 But all I get is

> (6) Could not resolve host: *******.eu-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com

And come to think about it if I want to have access to my pod and send some requests I should have an external-ip like `111.111.111.111` (obv an example).

**EDIT**

the deployment's yaml is:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: charting-rest-server
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: charting-rest-server
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: charting-rest-server
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: charting-rest-server
        image: *****.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/charting-rest-server:latest
        ports: 
          - containerPort: 5000
```

the service's yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name:  charting-rest-server-service
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: charting-rest-server
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 5000
```

I already tried with the suggestions from the comments , using an ingress instance but I only ended up spending a huge amount of time trying to understand how they work , "am I doing something wrong"?/etc .

I will put the yaml file I used here but it made no change since my ADDRESS field was empty - no ip to use.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: charting-rest-server-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: charting-rest-server-service
    http:
      paths:
      - path:/
        backend:
          serviceName: charting-rest-server-service
          servicePort: 80
```

I am stuck in that problem for so much time so I would appreciate some help.

Comment: Do you have an ingress object to setup http path routing for your application? `kubectl get ingress`

Comment: Please post `yaml` files for your pod, service and deployment. If you do also for ingress.

Comment: Updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already created a `Service` with type `LoadBalancer`, but it looks like you have incorrect ports configured.

Your `Deployment` is created with `containerPort: 5000` and your `Service` is pointing to `targetPort: 9376`. Those needs to match for the `Deployment` to be exposed.

If you are having a hard time writing `yaml` for the `Service` you can expose the `Deployment` using following kubectl command:

```
kubectl expose --namespace=tick deployment charting-rest-server --type=LoadBalancer --port=8765 --target-port=5000 --name=charting-rest-server-service
```

Once you fix those ports you will be able to access the service from outside using it's hostname:

```
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - hostname: aba02b223436111ea85ea06a051f04d8-1294697222.eu-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com
```

I also recommend this guide [Tutorial: Expose Services on your AWS Quick Start Kubernetes cluster](http://docs.heptio.com/content/tutorials/aws-qs-services-elb.html).

If you need more control over the http rules please consider using [`ingress`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/), you can read more about [ALB Ingress Controller on Amazon EKS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/alb-ingress.html) also [Using a Network Load Balancer with the NGINX Ingress Controller on Amazon EKS](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/network-load-balancer-nginx-ingress-controller-eks/).

Comment: I just updated the question. As far as I understood ingress is not needed for not complex apps , but even using one I cannot access the service-pod

Comment: @FloraBiletsiou, you would be better of posting a new question with all needed info instead of fully changing existing one.